# Spring Boot <absolute-ordering/> and metadata-complete="true" done with java config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a Spring Boot app. In that app, all my config is done with java config and currently i needed to add to my configuration two new security related entries, i.e.

```
metadata-complete="true"

<absolute-ordering/>
```

Till now i did not had web.xml file in my project. My question is how to configure those two features with java config i.e. no XML.

Here is an example of my current web.xml (located in "src/main/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml") file that i need to convert to java config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         version="3.1"
         metadata-complete="true"
             >
   <absolute-ordering/>

</web-app>
```

Comment: The answer probably depends on what you mean, and how you launch your app. Is it a WAR in a container, or are you running as an embedded container? What does `<absolute-ordering/>` (or `metadata-complete="true"`) have to do with security?

Comment: Hello Dave, I am running embedded container, and the answer to your question what "absolute-ordering" and metadata-complete="true"  has to with security , you can find in that video here http://www.infoq.com/presentations/spring-app-security   , in order to spare you the whole video click around minute 49.

Comment: you most probably know that person it is the guy that created SPNEGO Extension (kerberos) for spring

Comment: In an embedded container I don't think those properties in web.xml have any meaning, so you should be good to go.

Comment: are you sure about that ,,, you mean that if someone write a library and somewhere in this library a class implements the WebApplicationInitializer and overrides the onStartup method, he will not be able to change the existing servlet config or add a new one ? Dave can you please confirm that!

Comment: Yes I can confirm that. Spring Boot does not process `WebApplicationInitializers`.

Comment: thank you Dave, if you want you can put that as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an embedded container I don't think those properties in web.xml have any meaning, so you should be good to go. Spring Boot does not process `WebApplicationInitializers` (for example).